# The amount in Metamask and geth doesn't match

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

I made account with this `geth account new`

my public key is here

`0x3BA1FC2455d334526e3034C63681B28884B46c1F`

then import this in Meta Mask and get `3ETH` from `https://faucet.metamask.io/`

in Metamask there is shown `3ETH`

Then in local cli,

`geth --rinkeby --verbosity 0 console`

start console and

`eth.getBalance("0x3BA1FC2455d334526e3034C63681B28884B46c1F")`

However, It shows `0` not `3`

Why does this happen??

---

I am syncing with rinkeby by this command

`geth --rinkeby --port 31303`

checking progress.After this, I will    report again.

```
>eth.syncing

{
  currentBlock: 6072691,
  healedBytecodeBytes: 0,
  healedBytecodes: 0,
  healedTrienodeBytes: 0,
  healedTrienodes: 0,
  healingBytecode: 0,
  healingTrienodes: 0,
  highestBlock: 9935848,
  startingBlock: 6009561,
  syncedAccountBytes: 1323975833,
  syncedAccounts: 9094732,
  syncedBytecodeBytes: 6743036861,
  syncedBytecodes: 959409,
  syncedStorage: 131658286,
  syncedStorageBytes: 28911965362
}
> eth.blockNumber
0
```

Comment: Most likely your `geth` isn't yet fully synced with the current state of the blockchain. When you enable some level of verbosity, you should see the syncing status.

Comment: Thanks @Petr , maybe I am still syncing process. I updated the article, I will check later.